# jQuery.clone() of table does NOT create dom element

Tags: jquery, html2canvas

Environment: 
  Google Chrome (Version 48.0.2564.109 m) // 
  jQuery jQuery v1.11.3 // html2canvas 0.4.1

I am cloning a rather sophisticated table - to then print it via html2canvas

```
html2canvas($(el), {
    onrendered: function(canvas) {                                      
        var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
        var imgWindow = window.open(img);
    }
});
```

This works wonderfully if done directly on the original table with $('#masterplan') but fails if done on a clone (as below)

```
var clonedTable = jQuery('#masterplan').clone();
```

The console output $('#masterplan') also looks different (root 0:table missing) to what the clone looks like, why?!

```
console.log($('#masterplan'))

[table#masterplan.dataTable, context: document, selector: "#masterplan"]
    **0: table#masterplan.dataTable**
    context: document

console.log($('#clonedTable'))

[context: document, selector: "#clonedTable"]
    context: document
```

Subsequently - while $el.getElementsByTagName (..) works on the original - it fails on the clone.

jQuery bug, Clemens error :D?

Comment: But do you add cloned element to the DOM? And btw, you aren't changing its ID attribute to match `#clonedTable` selector. And i'm still not sure why would you need to clone it?!

Comment: @A.Wolff - thank you.. reason is very simple : I want to modify it before I print it (e.g. adding a few lines (e..g filter picked etc). do I need to change the attribute. Can you provide an example of adding it to the dom?